# Can a HTTPS server deliberately reject clients who don't authenticate said server?

Tags: authentication, https, oauth-2.0

Let's suppose a HTTPS connection has just been formed but the server doesn't yet know who the client is. The client is about to pass some pre-agreed secret through the tunnel to prove its identity to the server.

If the client is foolish enough to send this secret without authenticating the server first, then the server should fear that the secret might have been leaked, in which case it should not accept the secret as authentication.

Can a server be programmed to behave in this way using the usual HTTP(S) tools?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the scenario. What is the nature of "authenticating the server" that goes above and beyond what's already done in the TLS handshake before any HTTPS stuff starts happening?

Comment: HTTPS doesn't require either party to authenticate the other. It's an option you can switch on and off. I'd like the server to know whether or not the client has authenticated it and switch its behaviour accordingly.